# Getting my own IP address using getsockname()

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, udp

I'm trying to get my own IP address by trying to connect() to 8.8.8.8 using `UDP` socket and then calling `getsockname()` function.

I've written a function `get_my_ip()`, and the code worked when it was placed in my server program, but as a separate function, it fails. It prints some strange characters instead of my IP address.

The only thing I changed from the code in my server program was return NULL instead of return 1, or return 2, because it was inside `int main()`.

Can anyone see why my program is not working?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must initialize addrlen.

```
addrlen = sizeof remoteaddr;
getsockname(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&remoteaddr, &addrlen);
```

Answer (score 2):

You must cast the `sin_addr` in your `inet_ntop()` call. It should be like this:

```
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(((struct sockaddr_in *)sa)->sin_addr), remoteIP, addrlen);

inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(((struct sockaddr_in6 *)sa)->sin6_addr), remoteIP, addrlen);
```